# What hold and inject pressure to be used in microinjection?

Tags: molecular-genetics, mutations, drosophila

I am planning to set up micro-injection apparatus in our lab. Normally what hold and inject pressures are used to inject DNA in fly embryo? I couldn't find in any literature as far as I've come across.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on volume that you want to inject and the width of your needle! Try to optimize the pressure by measuring the volume that you inject in mineral oil (I use grid in the objective to measure the drop size). You will decrease the volume by decreasing the injection pressure, of course. I work with zebrafish embryos so I am not sure if it is the same since it's in the water, but for DNA injection (1-2 nL) I normally use Hold Pressure 2 kPa and Injection Pressure 20-30 kPa.

Comment: That sounds similar to what I was using. We pulled our own micropipettes from borosilicate glass though, so had total control of the size. Edit I think we used 40kPa for 50 microseconds maybe, or milliseconds, whichever sounds more normal.

Comment: @Tamara Spika, I standardized the parameters (Micropipette size, inject and hold pressure) according to my need. But most of the time, when I try to inject in mineral oil, the water does not come out. I mean, the needle gets clogged. Do u have any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: @Mosquitoman Did you try to increase the pressure (like 10 fold) and press  once just to clear your needle and then try to inject again?